# Bindable not getting notified

Tags: android, android-databinding, bindable

```
@Bindable
public String getFirstName() { 
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
}

@Bindable
public String getLastName() { 
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName);
}


@Bindable({"firstName", "lastName"})
public void getName() { 
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; 
}
```

Above code I picked up from Google's sample code - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Bindable

And using it in XML like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_name"
    .....
    android:text="@{myViewModel.firstName}" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_name"
    .....
    android:text="@{myViewModel.lastName}" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/full_name"
    .....
    android:text="@{myViewModel.getName()}" />
```

Whenever I am calling `myViewModel.setFirstName("Mohammed");` it is updating the first name in view but not the full name. Even the documentations are buggy and not reliable.

Other posts related to this issue could not help much as most of them deal with non parameterised Bindables.

As per this line in doc

> Whenever either firstName or lastName has a change notification, name will also be considered dirty. This does not mean that onPropertyChanged(Observable, int) will be notified for BR.name, only that binding expressions containing name will be dirtied and refreshed.

I also tried calling `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);` but it also has no effect on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after thorough analysis of databinding concepts, I found out that when we call `notifyPropertyChanged` on `BaseObservable` class it actually notifies the property but not the getters and setters.

So in my question above, there are no changes in the JAVA part, but the change was required in XML part.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_name"
    .....
    android:text="@{myViewModel.firstName}" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_name"
    .....
    android:text="@{myViewModel.lastName}" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/full_name"
    .....
    android:text="@{myViewModel.name}" />
```

Since I am declaring `getName()` as `Bindable({"firstName", "lastName"})`, databinding generates the property `name` so I have to listen for `myViewModel.name` instead of `myViewModel.getName()` in my XML. And we don't even have to notify `name` for change, notifying just the `firstName` or `lastName` will notify the property `name` because of parameterised Bindable.

But make sure that the

Comment: Cool, BTW i did not notice you are using `myViewModel.getName()`. Binding does not use method name syntax, it will find name accessor. So always use fields name.

Comment: That is one of the last thing anyone would notice, even the docs had no clarity. But if we are listening for property, then just the parameterised Bindables will do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hack

```
public class Modal {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String name;

    @Bindable
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }


    @Bindable
    public void getName() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for breaking the party, But I found the actual solution. Their documentation is bad. Had to break the head to understand this databinding concept.

Comment: If you are already using this hack anywhere in your code, then I would recommend you to take a look at my answer. Though this is a good working hack, I managed to find the actual solution.